# Angular 2 Sort List Animations

Tags: javascript, angular

I would post the code but I really don't even know where to start.  I've read through the https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html animation guide but it doesn't answer to my requirement.

So, let say you have a list of items displayed using `*ngFor` and on top of the list contains sort buttons.  Example say the default sort is 'Name'.  It'll show like this on the initial screen

```
Sort By: Name | Value
[name: a, value:3]
[name: b, value:2]
[name: c, value:1]
```

then let say the user presses 'Value' to sort by Value.

```
Sort By: Name | Value
[name: c, value:1]
[name: b, value:2]
[name: a, value:3]
```

I know that I can simply sort the list that is binded to the View Component but I wanted to be animated.  Is this even possible with current Angular 2 Animation API?

Comment: I have a similar issue, though for me, I'd be OK with enter/leave animations for each moved element. As it is, if you reorder items in the list, it doesn't trigger * => void and I don't see how to react to it at all.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, the idea is to have all elements rendered at all time. Instead we just change each elements attributes based on their order, therefore it'll trigger the animation.

I just made a very simple ones to show the idea.

```js
angular.module('StackApp', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  'use strict';

  $scope.title = 'List';
  var item1 = { title: "orange", pos: 1 };
  var item2 = { title: "apple", pos: 2 };
  var item3 = { title: "banana", pos: 3 };
  
  $scope.items = [item1, item2, item3];
  
  $scope.sort = function() {
    item1.pos = 2;
    item2.pos = 1;
  }
  
});
```

```css
ul li {
  -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
}

.pos1 {
  padding-left: 1px;
}
.pos2 {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.pos3 {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="StackApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <button ng-click="sort()">Sort</button>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="'pos' + item.pos">{{ item.title }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is about horizontally located elements, but you can use the idea and implement it for vertical elements in such way:

1. Make all item divs position: ansolute and with same height. Set parent div height as sum of elements height with ngStyle.

Set transition in css for each item div.

2. Set top of each element according to the index
3. On sorting recalculate the top for each item (I think you can add additional prop to array item and apply it with ngStyle

So item top values change should be affected with transition.

Ps u can use translate transform also